# junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `a' while defining a .double hex value

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm64, gnu-assembler

While defining a variable in a section like this,

```
.section ".__mydebug", "aw"
mydstart:   .double 0x123456789abcdef0
myptr:  .double 0x8888888899999999
```

I get

```
arch/arm64/kernel/head.S:994: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `a'
```

If I change `0x123456789abcdef0` to `0x1234567890000000`, it compiles ok. So it seems the compiler (gcc) doesn't understand the hex chanaracters. I tried `0x123456789ABCDEF0` but it's the same error starting from `A`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.double` is for assembling floating-point values.](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Double.html#Double)

If you want the 64-bit integer `0x123456789abcdef0`, use `.dword` or `.xword` or `.8byte`.

Comment: Ah! Many thanks! (I should read basic documents ..)